# My new account is brand new and I can't submit answers

Tags: support, answers, user-accounts, post-ban

Today I've seen an user requesting help for a bug which I have stumbled upon and I'd like to share my solution with him.
My account is pristine (Angular wink), at least I don't remember to have answer, or to have posted any question at all.

Yeah, I've been a Lurker. And now, when I finally have found someone to help, as soon as I click on Post Answer a beautiful message tells me:
"We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."
[image]

I've read the Help Center. At least trying to guess what could be going on. I've never answered a question during all this time.
I've never posted any question during all this time.

Maybe I am missing some details but let me share a profile pic so maybe you can guide me towards finding a solution, so I can help a guy which is requesting help with his Angular project.

[image]

Not sure what this Reputation(1) means but there is nothing there:
[image]

I have even completed the Tours to earn the badges....
So basically I am totally clueless...
The only bit is the "Automagic filter" which autobans accounts following a Machine Learning pattern (probably). Not sure if the Vodoo magic is striking here. I am in a Center with tons of offices crowed of Developers :)

Thanks for your answers.

Edited: Following the comment suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is specific to Stack Overflow and should be migrated to MSO.

Comment: The FAQ post [_What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) notes "An automatic filter is in place to ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses... with a history of extremely poor posts. "

Comment: Sorry but this is not a duplicate of "posting questions" as far as I see @gnat. Here I am trying to send an Answer but not a Question. Also the answer giving there don't apply at all to me: I have never requested to delete a previous blocked account.

Comment: You said you are currently in a place where a lot of other devs are? That’s probably the problem. There were probably too many bad answers from that IP addr.

Comment: @Raedwald I read that post, and as you can see I am already trying to guess if that could be the problem (or not). Not sure, because I don't have any notification about the filter anywhere, if that is the issue or if this is a bug happening in the platform.

Comment: as you can see from the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334374/165773) posted by Stack Overflow [moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy), this is just the case covered by a duplicate. This is how [tag:anti-recidivism-system] works and it applies equally to question- and answer-banned user accounts

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I didn't see that tiny blue link of "deleted answers". Let's try to fix that then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your account isn't as brand new as you remember. On September 5th, you posted 5 answers that are little more than a link to another site. Those were downvoted and deleted. That is why you are blocked from answering.

You should still be able to see them (at least for the next day or so) if you go to your profile, view your answers and click on the link to view recently deleted answers.

Comment: Wow. My deeply apologizes. I didn't see them at all. I mean, I even didn't remember I shared my solution (step by step) for those answers. Not sure why are deleted, maybe following the "barely more than a link to an external site" however the answer, several pages (as you can see) don't probably fit in SO. Now that at least I know the reason, I will try to find a solution. Thanks a lot! PS: that blue link "deleted recent answer" is for a newcomer totally off of vision. If you know what I mean.

Comment: Just to emphasize, I meant brand new as "interacting". Probably my unique interaction, and September 5th is not even a month ago. Thanks for pointing me the issue!